# Python "IndentationError: expected an indented block"

Tags: python

I just downloaded my old project to a new computer, and I'm getting an Indentation Error where there wasn't one before.

I originally created this on a Ubuntu computer, now I'm trying to run it on a Windows 10 computer. It was created in 2.7 but we have updated it to python 3. I double checked that there are no tabs, only spaces, and I can't find any reason for an error.

```
def get_dirs(self):
    """Return an AppDirs object for the relevant OS."""
    return appdirs.AppDirs('West Tower', 'Patch-n-Kev')

def get_dirs(self):
  ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: Something to do with Unix vs Windows newlines?

Comment: Do you have more core inside `get_dirs()`? Why do you have to methods with the same name?

Comment: Can you please show few previous line? Because I think it's happening there.

Comment: Adding to @sam: Without a [MCVE], we can't help, and `SyntaxError`s (and their subclasses, like `IndentationError`), are almost never diagnosable without the preceding and subsequent lines.

Comment: The problem generally occurs because of an empty block *before* this code. Please see the linked duplicate for details.

Answer (score 0):

sample program:

```
if err: #or something that might cause another error

def f():
    pass

f()
```

**when i run:**

```
def f():
      ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```